Error during installing fbprophet using pip
During installation of fbprophet using pip
pip install fbprophet

I get the below error
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Temp\pip-install-x6r708ug\pystan_070c5d6edc6b4b1297b5563f051a1284\setup.py", line 122, in <module>
          from Cython.Build.Inline import _get_build_extension
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

Can you please suggest some tips

No module name Cython - have you tried installing it pip install Cython?

fbprophet is no longer maintained. Instead of using fbprophet, please use its recent version prophet.
According to the docs

As of v1.0, the package name on PyPI is “prophet”; prior to v1.0 it was “fbprophet”.

Note that the stable release of prophet requires: Python >=3.7.
